# Add a Vertical QToolBar to the bottom of QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qtoolbar, qstatusbar

I have a QMainWindow to which I need to add a vertical toolbar. The problem is that if I use QMainWindow::AddToolbar(Qt::BottomToolBarArea, toolbar) it will ignore  QToolbar::SetOrientation(Qt::Vertical).

Is there a way to force the orientation or add it to a different place at the bottom of the QMainWindow so that it's still below all the side panel Widgets?

I tried adding it to my QStatusBar, but couldn't get it to work without messing up the layout of the status bar, which I need to remain intact.

Comment: What would be the benefit of having a *vertical* toolbar at the bottom of the window? Can you provide a proper case scenario (or valid explanation) for this requirement, possibly with an image example of what it would look like?

Comment: Looks like non sense to me. The top and bottom borders of a window are horizontal, how is a toolbar expected to be on those borders while being vertical?